# Flutter Desktop: How can I generate an installer for macOS and distribute it to other users?

Tags: macos, flutter, flutter-desktop

I can generate the launcher for macOS but it only works on my mac, when I want to run it on another mac it says that the file is damaged. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you copying to the other macOS machine, and how? The built application is fully self contained and will run fine if correctly copied. For instance, just zipping the application in Finder and copying that should work.

Comment: Any updates? I hope there is a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can open macos folder of your flutter project with xcode and click on the archieve option in product menu then you can distribute that archieve

Comment: Where to find the archive?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are signing it to run only on your device locally. Yesterday I had this problem. Today I figured it out. The solution is pretty easy:

Open the macOS Xcode Project and go to Runner, then select Signing & Capabilities. Select a signing team, then choose `development` in the `signing certificate` dropdown.

Run `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` then `flutter build macos --release`

Hope it helps you as it helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You need to notarize the app to fix this error.

Here some link

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution

WWDC 2019 video on the same topic

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/703/

Process brief

XCode -> Product -> Archive

After archive process done
Distribute app -> Developer ID -> Upload